# Logarithm on absolute values

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

I need to solve this equation for y (C is just a constant):

$\ln(|y|) = \ln(|x|) + C$

Using the exponential function I'd get:

$|y|=|x| + e^C $

But my textbook says the solution should be:

$|y|=|x|\cdot e^C $ and thus $y =\pm xe^C$

Why is it $\cdot$ instead of +?

Comment: Usint the e function you would get $|y| =|x|\cdot e^C$.  You would not get $|x| + e^c$.  Remeber $e^{a+b} = e^a\times e^b$. Not $e^a + e^b$.

Answer (score 3):

In general, $e^{a+b}=e^a\cdot e^b$. So when you apply the exponential function to $|x|+C$ you get $e^{|x|+C}=e^{|x|}\cdot e^C$.

Comment: Im stupid, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ represent the right side of your equation and $B$ represent the left side.

Then $B=D$ and $e^B=e^D$.

We know $D=ln|x|+C$ so $e^{ln|x|+C}=e^{ln|x|}e^C=|x|*e^C$

We used the fact that $e^{x+y}=e^x *e^y$

Answer (score 0):

Why is it $*$ instead of $+$?

Because $M^{u+ w} = M^u* M^w$ and it is not true that $M^{u+w} = M^u + M^w$

Althought we are *long* past the point where we can thin of $M^u$ as $\underbrace{M\times M\times ....M}_{u\text{ times}}$, so $M^{u+v}=\underbrace{M\times M\times ....M}_{u+v\text{ times}} = \underbrace{M\times M\times ....M}_{u\text{ times}}\times \underbrace{M\times M\times ....M}_{v\text{ times}}$, we *still* have $M^{u+v}= M^u*M^v$ as a basic exponent identity.